# Add a product to the cart with custom option file or image

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

already try with following code, but stuck when try to add option type of file

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(611);

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

//the file stored in http://domain/img1.png
$image= 'img1.png';
$params = array(
    'product' => $product->getId(), // This would be $product->getId()
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        2 => "text field here",
        1 => array(
            'quote_path' => Mage::getBaseDir() . $image,
            'secret_key' => substr(md5(file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir() . $image)), 0, 20)
            ),

    ),
    'options_1_file_action'=>'save_new',
);      



try {   
    $cart->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($params));
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $cart->save();

    echo 'success';
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

found this but the answer not clearly
[How to set a custom option of type "file" when adding a product to the cart in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801535/how-to-set-a-custom-option-of-type-file-when-adding-a-product-to-the-cart-in-m)

Thanks in advance :)